# Django Form submit Through ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am pretty new to Ajax. i am trying to catch all the concepts.I am trying to submit a form through ajax. here's my code

views.py:

```
def ajax_test1(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = ModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print request.POST.get('name')
            x = request.POST.get('name')
            if request.is_ajax():
                response_dict = {}
                response_dict.update({'server_response':x})
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_dict),content_type='application/json')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('not ok')
    else:
        form = ModelForm()
    return render(request,'test1.html',{'form':form})
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function{
        var input_id =  $('#id_name').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/test1/',
            datatype:'json',
            data:{name:input_id},
            success: function(json){
                $('result').append(json.server_response);
            },
            headers:{'X-CSRFToken':csrf_token},
            error: function(xhr,errmsg,err){
                alert('Something worng');
            }
        });
    });   
});
```

Html:

```
<form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form }}

    <p><input id="button" type="submit" value="Continue &rarr;"></p>
    </form>

    <div id="result">

    </div>
    <div id="result1">

    </div>
```

The above code return 200 Response but data is not saving,and it return ServerResponse:Undefined

Comment: whitespace is important in python, could you please fix the formatting in your question to correctly show your code? (Using Ctrl+K might help do this)

Comment: response json will be `{'server_response': <name>}` so you can get the name via `json.server_response` instead of `json.name`.

Comment: I edited the question. anyone can help me with this please?

Comment: The code you've provided looks correct to me, are there any errors that occur when stepping through the code? how are you verifying that data is saved?